# How do i fix this Opencv ffmpeg related error?

Tags: opencv, yolo

I am having problems while compiling my yolov3 model. each time I try to compile I am thrown with 2 warnings and an error:

```
C:\Users\320\Desktop\video-streaming>[INFO] loading YOLO from disk...
sdjfonrfoknokl 'C:/Users/320/Desktop/video-streaming/input_videos/airport.mp4'
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:901)
warning: 'C:/Users/320/Desktop/video-streaming/input_videos/airport.mp4' (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:902)
[INFO] 0 total frames in video
[INFO] cleaning up...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\320\Desktop\video-streaming\yolo_video.py", line 166, in <module>
    writer.release()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'release'
```

Comment: post your code maybe?

Comment: here is my github of the yolo_video.py file only! https://github.com/Mayureshk19/Subtle/blob/master/yolo_video.py @gameon67